# Cant cast org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow to org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow

Tags: eclipse, exception, casting

This is happening when code is migrated from Eclipse 3.x to 4.5 Mars, Java 6 to Java 8.

Throws exception while trying to cast to `ApplicationWindow` in this code:

```
CoolItem[] coolbarItems = ((ApplicationWindow)getWindowConfigurer().getWindow()).getCoolBarManager().getControl().getItems();
```

**Exception:**

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 4 2 2015-07-16 18:54:00.897

!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt". !STACK 0java.lang.**ClassCastException**: org.eclipse.ui.internal.**WorkbenchWindow cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow** at com.ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.setElementPathToolBar(ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:336) at
```

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse internals were substantially rewritten for Eclipse 4 and `WorkbenchWindow` is no longer derived from `ApplicationWindow` so you cannot do this cast. This was never really part of the defined API anyway.

To get the cool bar manager use:

```
getWindowConfigurer().getActionBarConfigurer().getCoolBarManager();
```

Comment: but i cant access getItems() through this.

Comment: Getting the items is not part of the Eclipse Coolbar API. You will have to find a way to do what you want that uses a proper API. Since you have not shown us where the code is running or what it is trying to do there is not much more I can say.

Comment: I tried like CoolItem[] coolbarItems = getWindowConfigurer().getActionBarConfigurer().getCoolBarManager().getItems();   but getItems() is of type IContributionItem[].I need to get items of type CoolItem[].

Comment: i am trying to get a list of toolbars from this and to be saved in coolbarItems

Comment: If I read the Eclipse code correctly the top trim bar no longer uses CoolItem. It is a number of toolbars and other controls.